# HP laptop doesn't show battery percentage

Tags: battery, acpi

Recently I dual-booted my Windows HP laptop with Ubuntu. Ubuntu doesn't detect a battery. At upstream kernel 5.4, the battery got detected but never went under 100%. If the laptop was booted plugged in to the adapter, a lightning symbol was displayed next to the battery, but when disconnected from the charger, I won't disappear. Apparently Ubuntu has no idea how to read out these values from the battery.

Several solutions found on the web were applied without a change of behavior.

My system is dual-booted with Windows 10. The battery status is correctly shown in Windows.

Secure boot is disabled.

I'm wondering if anyone has faced this issue himself and found a workaround.

```
:~$ lsb_release -rd
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
```

```
:~$ uname -r
5.10.2-051002-generic
```

```
:~$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
cat: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status: No such file or directory
```

```
:~$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
cat: /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state: No such file or directory
```

```
:~$ sudo apt-cache policy acpi
acpi:
  Installed: 1.7-1.1
  Candidate: 1.7-1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.7-1.1 500
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

ACPI related errors from `:~$ sudo dmesg`

```
[ 0.229715] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20200925/psobject-220)
[ 1.213005] battery: ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery absent)
[ 1.214643] hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
[ 1.486160] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
[ 1.486227] acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
[ 1.486457] acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
[ 1.503599] usb: port power management may be unreliable
```

Non-ACPI related errors from `:~$ sudo dmesg`

```
[ 1.486596] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:04: WQBJ data block query control method not found
[ 1.614067] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA328E:00: supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[ 1.614099] i2c_hid i2c-SYNA328E:00: supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[ 1.709308] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Timeout waiting for interrupt!
[ 1.709312] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
[ 1.711424] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Failed terminating the transaction
[ 1.711525] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus is busy, can't use it!
[ 1.756903] thunderbolt 0000:00:0d.2: 0: uid crc8 mismatch (expected: 0x8e, got: 0xe7)
[ 2.095956] thunderbolt 0000:00:0d.3: 0: uid crc8 mismatch (expected: 0x0, got: 0xdb)
[ 3.866634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[ 4.255298] thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[ 5.469973] hp_wmi: query 0x4c returned error 0x6
```

Remarkable info's from `:~$ sudo dmesg`

`[ 3.757921] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop ACPI-WMI Extras`
-- I'm on a HP laptop

GRUB kernel parameters: ""

Kernel params already tried with no change of behavior:

- `acpi=force`
- `acpi_osi=Windows`
- `acpi_osi=Linux`
- `pci=nocrs`

BIOS settings already tried with no change of behavior:

- Enabled `Battery remaining time`

Hardware:
HP ENVY 13-aq1006nb
with latest BIOS version `F14 rev. A`

Thanks

Comment: If applicable try disabling Fast Boot (UEFI) as well. And, as usual, disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: Fast Startup is disabled but this laptop is recently bought and I can't disable UEFI anymore in his BIOS.

Comment: UEFI is the new firmware that replaced BIOS. If you have one you don't have the other and of course you can't "disable UEFI". I meant disable Fast Boot, if applicable, in UEFI ("BIOS") settings. Reason is FB assumes no hardware change; disabling forces UEFI to re-initialize all hardware and that alone may change the situation you're in.

Comment: There's no such option unfortunately. Also, I can't find any CSM related tweak. Changing acpi kernel options sometimes make a difference, as in the recognition of the battery, but then it's capacity or status is still shown wrongly.

Comment: Try to set `Battery remaining time` to `Disabled`.

Comment: Yup, already did. It doesn't seem to make any difference unfortunately...